# Google Play Console Data Safety No data collected

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

**How can i set my app collect data**

> No data collected

> The developer says that this app doesn’t collect user data.

**But i want to set my app collect user data**

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [playconsole](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/?pli=1)
2. Select your app which you want to edit
3. At the left bottm corner under `Policy` select  `App Content`
4. There you can edit `Data collection and security`

Comment: what i have to change for make it data is collected

Comment: Yah you can do it there